# jquery .trigger runs 5 times

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have a weird problem, if I trigger .change the code inside .change performs 5 times until it jumps back. While debugging I can see how it jumps between line 15 and 25. First of all I would like to know why `$(this).addClass('teiedit');` doesnt add the class teiedit to the form-select class and second why does .trigger perform the code inside .change 5 times?

the code is on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/u8xmQZXU

Comment: If `.trigger()` is running that code five times, it's because you've bound the function five times.

Comment: Adding an event handler to an element doesn't override any existing event handlers on that element, even if they're both calling the same function. You've either a. bound the event handler to a single element five times or b. bound the event handler once each to five separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

how many times is attach called? you might want to try something like this to make sure the event is only bound once instead of 5 times:

```
var textarea = jQuery("#edit-body-und-0-value");
var grippie = textarea.parents('.resizable-textarea').find('.grippie');
var filter = jQuery('#edit-body-und-0-format--2');

$('.form-select').off();

// check if selection in text formats changes
$('.form-select').change(function() {
    ....
});
```

or you could try [namespacing](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) your events

Comment: I did, attach is called one time... I have set breakpoint on line 7 and that line gets called only one time

Comment: do you have only one .form-select visible at a time?

Comment: what is the $('.form-select').length?

Comment: the length is 5... there are 5 elements in that select form

Comment: ok attach is called 5 times yet... now I got it. So to solve my problem I am should use namespacing, ist that right? Or is there another better solution to get that js running if that particular element is selected in that box?

Comment: so you need to make sure you are selecting only the element which you want to apply that event handler to and you also could namespace the event or use $('.form-select').off(); like above to make sure you only attach one event handler. without really understanding more of your project its hard to give more specific advice than that

Comment: thanks for that, but I just asked for the filter after I call .change and added the editor separately to make sure it gets loaded while the first page load is called...

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly prefer watching events with data :

```
if(!$('.form-select').data('eventAttached')){
    $('.form-select').data('eventAttached',true);

    $('.form-select').change(function() {
        ....
    });
}
```

simple, effective, and not technical. Although namespacing is better.